# SAS Summarizing a Categorical Field

Tags: sas, summary

New to SAS and want to how to summarize a dataset containing categorical variables.

For example, I have a dataset containing whether students from two classrooms have passed or failed a particular class:

```
StudentID ClassRoom Pass
1         A         1
2         A         1
3         A         0
4         B         1
5         B         0
6         B         0
```

How using PROC MEANS or FREQ or whichever can I achieve results such as the follows:

```
ClassRoom   Pass_1  Pass_0  NOBS
A           2       1       3
B           1       2       3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post any code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Proc summary solves the problem, there are other ways to solve as well:

```
data have;
input StudentID ClassRoom $ Pass;
cards;
1 A 1
2 A 1
3 A 0
4 B 1
5 B 0
6 B 0
;
 run;

data have;
  set have;
  by classroom notsorted;
    if pass=1 then pass_1=1;
    else pass_0=1;
 run;
 proc summary data=Have  nway missing  ;
    class classroom ;
    var pass_1 pass_0 ;
    output out=want (drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=NOBS)) sum= ;
 run;
```